# How to downscale for an external display?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, screen, resolution

I intend to connect my old full HD TV as external display to a mid-2012 MacBook air.

While being "only" 1920×1080, the TV has 42", so each element would look ridiculously large. So I thought about "emulating" it to be, say, 4k, then downscale the signal to the 1080 the TV can handle.

Is there such a possibility?

- MacBookAir5,1
- Mojave 10.14.6
- Intel HD Graphics 4000 1536 MB

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you want to extend your desktop and not just mirror it:
The Mac does this by default, for more fine grained options go to System Preferences → Screen, a window for the TV will appear, where scaling options is avaliable. For even more options hold down the <kbd>Alt</kbd>/<kbd>Option</kbd> key while clicking on "Scaled"

Comment: Hello @Harker, thanks for the tipp with pressing "alt". True, I can set the resolution below the screens capability, but my aim is to set it ABOVE (as far as apps are concerned) and downsample right before sending to HDMI.